# how to set customer ip address in Authorize.net PHP SDK?

Tags: php, authorize.net

i am using Authorize.net PHP SDK in our website for credit card payments. currently  i am sending customer bill to information like customer firstname, lastname, address, zip, city, state, country and email.
i need to send customer ip address also. please suggest the solution.
a part of current codes look like this :

```html
public function authorize_card($data) {
  // Create the payment data for a credit card
  $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
  $creditCard->setCardNumber($data['card_no']);
  $creditCard->setExpirationDate($data['card_exp']);
  $creditCard->setCardCode($data['card_cvc']);
  
  $paymentCreditCard = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
  $paymentCreditCard->setCreditCard($creditCard);
  
  //create a transaction
  $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
  $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction"); 
  $transactionRequestType->setAmount($data['amount']);
  $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentCreditCard);
  
  
  $billto = new AnetAPI\CustomerAddressType();
  $billto->setFirstName($data['bill_fname']);
  $billto->setLastName($data['bill_lname']);
  $billto->setAddress($data['bill_address']);
  $billto->setCity($data['bill_city']);
  $billto->setState($data['bill_state']);
  $billto->setZip($data['bill_zip']);
  $billto->setCountry($data['bill_country']);
  
  $bill_response = $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($billto);

  $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
  $request->setMerchantAuthentication($this->auth);
  $request->setRefId($this->refId);
  $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
  $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
  $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse($this->api_mode);
 
  if ($response != null) {
   $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
   
   if ($tresponse != null && ($tresponse->getResponseCode() == 1 ||      $tresponse->getResponseCode() == 253)) {
    $response_array = array();
    $response_array['auth_code'] = $tresponse->getAuthCode();
    $response_array['auth_transaction_id'] = $tresponse->getTransId();
    return $response_array;
   } else {
    $errors = $tresponse->geterrors();
    
    if (is_array($errors) && !empty($errors)) {
     return $errors[0]->geterrorText();
    } else {
     $message = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
     return $message[0]->getText();
    }
   }
   
  } else {
   return "Charge Credit card Null response returned";
  }
}
```

Comment: Good luck getting a sensible IP address, or even being allowed to do this in some locales. This is probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3003145/1531971

Comment: the link you posted is for getting customer ip address in php. my question is about setting customer ip address in authorizeNet php sdk to send it as customer info.

Comment: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Does-Authorize-net-pass-on-Customer-IP-Address/td-p/65050 (It appears you are supposed to ask your web app for this.)

Comment: actually they are not that supportive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually i have figured it out. there is a method given in autorizeNet php sdk to set customer ip address.
method is setCustomerIP()
which need to be used with TransactionRequestType class.
the final codes would look like this:

```html
public function authorize_card($data) {
  // Create the payment data for a credit card
  $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
  $creditCard->setCardNumber($data['card_no']);
  $creditCard->setExpirationDate($data['card_exp']);
  $creditCard->setCardCode($data['card_cvc']);
  
  $paymentCreditCard = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
  $paymentCreditCard->setCreditCard($creditCard);
  
  //create a transaction
  $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
  $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction"); 
  $transactionRequestType->setAmount($data['amount']);
  $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentCreditCard);
    
    //Setting customer ip address
    $transactionRequestType->setCustomerIP($data['ip']);
  
  
  $billto = new AnetAPI\CustomerAddressType();
  $billto->setFirstName($data['bill_fname']);
  $billto->setLastName($data['bill_lname']);
  $billto->setAddress($data['bill_address']);
  $billto->setCity($data['bill_city']);
  $billto->setState($data['bill_state']);
  $billto->setZip($data['bill_zip']);
  $billto->setCountry($data['bill_country']);
  
  $bill_response = $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($billto);

  $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
  $request->setMerchantAuthentication($this->auth);
  $request->setRefId($this->refId);
  $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
  $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
  $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse($this->api_mode);
 
  if ($response != null) {
   $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
   
   if ($tresponse != null && ($tresponse->getResponseCode() == 1 || $tresponse->getResponseCode() == 253)) {
    $response_array = array();
    $response_array['auth_code'] = $tresponse->getAuthCode();
    $response_array['auth_transaction_id'] = $tresponse->getTransId();
    return $response_array;
   } else {
    $errors = $tresponse->geterrors();
    
    if (is_array($errors) && !empty($errors)) {
     return $errors[0]->geterrorText();
    } else {
     $message = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
     return $message[0]->getText();
    }
   }
   
  } else {
   return "Charge Credit card Null response returned";
  }
}
```

Comment: I really do not know why this answer was down voted. It answered the exact same question I had. Thank you.